# Family Guy "Wish it. Want it. Do it." based on a real book?

Tags: family-guy

[http://www.amazon.com/Wish-Want-Do/dp/1483998584](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1483998584)

The author is Brian H. Griffin. Is this book real? I thought it was a joke but it is a printed version and is on Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it worth noting that the book was published in 2013 while the original episode aired back in 2010, so it is safe to say the episode was not based on the book.  It is more likely that the opposite is true, based on the wikipedia page [for the episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Writes_a_Bestseller#Influence) (the "Influence" section mentions the book).

From the wikipedia page:

> A book with the same title by a quasi homonymous author, Brian H. Griffin, is available on Amazon.com. It should be noted that the author pictured in the back cover isn't the animated character Brian Griffin. Just as the book described in the episode, its content consists in truisms and blank pages.

Answer (score 0):

The book is a joke. It's based off Brian's book. If you buy the book you would see that most of the pages are blank.